# JSF Liferay Exception

Tags: jsf, liferay, liferay-6

I try to use my portlet from liferay 6.0.6 on 6.1.1 and get follow stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.icesoft.faces.component.menubar.MenuItemRenderer.makeTopLevelAnchor(MenuItemRenderer.java:350)
at com.icesoft.faces.component.menubar.MenuItemRenderer.renderAnchor(MenuItemRenderer.java:705)

org.portletfaces.bridge.BridgeException: javax.faces.FacesException
at org.portletfaces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:449)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.menubar.MenuItemRenderer.makeTopLevelAnchor(MenuItemRenderer.java:350)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.menubar.MenuItemRenderer.renderAnchor(MenuItemRenderer.java:705)
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay just released [Liferay Faces 3.1.0](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/overview) which is designed to work with Liferay 6.1.x. Recommend that you upgrade from PortletFaces Bridge to [Liferay Faces Bridge](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/bridge):